# How to cat contents of a file to another file in ExecStartPre?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to implement the [JSON authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file) to authenticate against Google Container Registry.This method requires Service Account JSON key file to be passed during authentication. 
Is it possible to pass the content of the JSON as a variable instead of the credentials itself? I would not want to do that security region.

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/cat > keyfile.json << EOF
                                {
<file path>
                                }
                                EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run your `ExecStartPre` in shell, eg.

```
/bin/sh -c "<commands>"
```

or place the contents in separate shell script and point `ExecStartPre` to it.

Comment: Thanks @sebasth I tried: ```Tried:

ExecStartPre= /bin/sh -c " -/usr/bin/cat > keyfile.json << EOF 
                                {
                                  "xxxx",
                                    "zzzz"
                                }
                                EOF "


It failed with error:
```
* data.ct_config.service: data.ct_config.service: error converting to Ignition: error at line 77, column 17
invalid unit content: unexpected newline encountered while parsing option name
``` Its not liking the multiple lines inside the {}? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: if you want to wrap long lines in unit file, you need to add `\\` before newline.